# Garbage collection suspended coroutine task

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I am using kotlin coroutines to show confirmation dialogs and process the result.

```
suspend fun showConfirmationDialog() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { cont ->
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", { _, _ -> cont.resume(true) })
            .setNegativeButton("No", { _, _ -> cont.resume(false) })
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setOnCancelListener { cont.cancel() }
            .create()

    dialog.show()
    cont.invokeOnCompletion { dialog.dismiss() }
}
```

But I feel this code is susceptible to memory leak, in case continuation is not resumed the task would be running forever. What would be the right way to cancel the task ?

Comment: Why not separate the concerns properly? Have your coroutine signal your viewmodel/presenter/whatever, bubble the notification up, have your UI (Activity, Fragment, etc.) observe the signal, and wait for the UI to send another signal to the view model with the user's response, then have your viewModel/presenter/whatever, bubble the signal down again towards the repository/wherever the coroutine is, so it can do what it has to do. You're putting all the eggs in the same basket.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini If you compare the two approaches, the above solution can be as simple as 
`
val answer = fetchNumberFromDialog1() + fetchNumberFromDialog2() vs 

fetchNumberFromDialog().observe(a -> fetchNumberFromDialog2.observe( b -> {} )

`

Comment: basically is there a way to observe for the response without using a callback introducing a nested level of code ? 

Is it possible to just do input = await askForInput()

Comment: Launch the coroutine in a controlled scope that you can eventually cancel.

Comment: I don't think those are the only alternatives. You're simply syntax sugaring the same at the expense of mixing responsibilities in my opinion. If you need to flag a process then you need some Mixin class or similar or even a repo that can manage this for you. Your dialog should be handled by your presentation (viewmodel->fragment/act) and that should be absolutely irrelevant to the coroutine. Again, it's just a matter of preference. I wouldn't do what you're doing, but I'm not in your shoes :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach is unusual these days, but if it makes sense for your program then it's fine.

BUT, when you call `suspendCoroutine`, you MUST make sure that the `Continuation` you get back will be resumed.  That's not just because of memory leaks.  There can be all kinds of important things that need to happen in `finally` blocks that will only run if the `Continuation` is resumed -- releasing locks, closing files and connections, etc. etc.

If an exception is thrown during dialog construction or `show`, your coroutine will just not suspend, so that is taken care of already.

But, make sure there's no way that dialog can close without the continuation being resumed. You probably want to use `onDismissListener`.

Also, I'm not aware of an `invokeOnCompletion` method or extension for `CancellableContinuation`...  Make sure it does what you want, or just don't use it.

I would handle dismissal more directly, like this:

```
suspend fun showConfirmationDialog() : Boolean {
    var dialog : Dialog?
    try {
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { cont ->
            val newDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", { _, _ -> cont.resume(true) })
                .setNegativeButton("No", { _, _ -> cont.resume(false) })
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setOnDismissListener { dialog = null;cont.cancel() }
                .create()

            newDialog.show()
            dialog = newDialog
        }
    } finally {
        dialog?.dismiss()
    }
}
```